# having trouble with inserting data to a database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

When I enter data to a database using the sample code below, the line `System.out.println("Insertion complete")` is shown on the console. When I go to the database, I find that the stored data is a blank.

I think the problem could be my sqlquery, but I don't see any problem with it.

Here is an example of my code:

```
public class SignUpFrame extends JFrame {

    public SignUpFrame() {

        super("SIGN UP");   
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocation(500, 250);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);    

        ImageIcon FrameIcon = new ImageIcon("images/signup.png");
        JLabel frameicon = new JLabel(FrameIcon);
        frameicon.setBounds(150, 0, 100, 100);
        add(frameicon);


        JLabel firstNamelbl,LastNameLbl,EmailAddressLbl,PasswordLbl,ConfirmPasswordLbl;

        JTextField firstNametxt,LastNametxt,EmailAddresstxt;
        JPasswordField passwordtxt,ConfirmPasswordtxt;
        JButton OKbtn;
        JButton CANCELbtn;

        firstNamelbl  = new JLabel("FIRST NAME:");
        firstNametxt = new JTextField();
        firstNametxt.setBounds(150, 110, 200, 20);
        firstNamelbl.setBounds(50, 110, 100, 20);

        LastNameLbl = new JLabel("USERNAME:");
        LastNametxt = new JTextField();
        LastNametxt.setBounds(150, 140, 200, 20);
        LastNameLbl.setBounds(50,140, 100, 20);

        EmailAddressLbl = new JLabel("EMAIL ADDRESS:");
        EmailAddresstxt = new JTextField();
        EmailAddresstxt.setBounds(150, 170, 200, 20);
        EmailAddressLbl.setBounds(50, 170, 150, 20);

        PasswordLbl = new JLabel("PASSWORD:");
        passwordtxt = new JPasswordField();
        passwordtxt.setBounds(150, 200, 200, 20);
        PasswordLbl.setBounds(50, 200, 150, 20);

        ConfirmPasswordLbl = new JLabel("CONFIRM PASSWORD:");
        ConfirmPasswordtxt = new JPasswordField();
        ConfirmPasswordtxt.setBounds(200, 230, 150, 20);
        ConfirmPasswordLbl.setBounds(50, 230, 150, 20);

        add(firstNamelbl);
        add(firstNametxt);

        add(LastNameLbl);
        add(LastNametxt);

        add(EmailAddressLbl);
        add(EmailAddresstxt);

        add(PasswordLbl);
        add(passwordtxt);

        add(ConfirmPasswordLbl);
        add(ConfirmPasswordtxt);

        OKbtn = new JButton("OK");
        OKbtn.setBounds(100, 270, 50, 20);
        add(OKbtn);
        char [] pass = passwordtxt.getPassword();
        String passWord = new String(pass);


        String FIRSTNAME,USERNAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD;
         FIRSTNAME = firstNametxt.getText().toString();
         USERNAME =LastNametxt.getText().toString();
         EMAIL = EmailAddresstxt.getText().toString();
         PASSWORD = passWord;




        OKbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/System";
                String user = "root";
                String password = "";

                Connection con;
                try {
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                    String sqlquery = "insert into signUp_tb "+
                                       "(FirstName,UserName,Email,Password) values ('"+FIRSTNAME+"','"+USERNAME+"','"+EMAIL+"','"+PASSWORD+"')";

                    statement.executeUpdate(sqlquery);
                    System.out.println("Insertion complete");
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });




        CANCELbtn = new JButton("CANCEL");
        CANCELbtn.setBounds(170, 270, 100, 20);
        add(CANCELbtn);

        CANCELbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: What does `statement.executeUpdate(sqlquery);` return?

Comment: you proberbly can't get the connection instance. Add Class.forName("the-driver-name") to load the driver.

Comment: You should consider taking your SQL logic off of the EDT. You don't want that freezing up the GUI if your connection / query hangs.

Comment: @FreddyMorrison +1, for OP -  [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection, please learn how to use prepared statements with parameters to avoid that security bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize your `FIRSTNAME`, `USERNAME` etc in `ActionListener` for OK button. You had initialized those `Strings` when there was no input data, that's why everything was blank. You want to get `JTextFields` values *when* user presses button. Not before.

Tested on SQLite.

```
OKbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        char [] pass = passwordTxt.getPassword();
        String PASSWORD = new String(pass);

        String FIRSTNAME,USERNAME,EMAIL;
        FIRSTNAME = firstNameTxt.getText();
        USERNAME = lastNameTxt.getText();
        EMAIL = emailAddressTxt.getText();


        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/System";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "";

        Connection con;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            String sqlquery = "insert into signUp_tb "+
                               "(FirstName,UserName,Email,Password) values ('"+FIRSTNAME+"','"+USERNAME+"','"+EMAIL+"','"+PASSWORD+"')";

            statement.executeUpdate(sqlquery);
            System.out.println("Insertion complete");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

And `setVisible(true)` should be the last thing you do. Should look like:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    this.setVisible(true);
});
```

So you will launch it from EDT.

Edit: about `setLayout(null)` - Try those [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) .

> Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, **you should use
>   a layout manager if at all possible**. A layout manager makes it easier
>   to adjust to look-and-feel-dependent component appearances, to
>   different font sizes, to a container's changing size, and to different
>   locales. Layout managers also can be reused easily by other
>   containers, as well as other programs.

From [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute positioning)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

Comment: @BradleyJuma no problem. And actually, you don't need to call `.getText().toString()`. `getText()` already does what you need..and your code will be easier to read.